# How to add lock screen controls in Google cast using iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, google-cast, lockscreen

Does google cast iOS SDK support lock screen controls? YouTube shows controls in lock screen. How can I have this feature in my application? Iam using Cast v3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the iOS Cast SDK does not support lock screen controls.

Comment: Okay.Then how YouTube implemented this .?

Comment: YouTube is not the only app that is doing it; for example Google Play Music does a similar thing if I am not mistaking but neither of these apps use the Cast SDK for showing the lock screen controls; there are some approaches/tricks that officially requires a music file to be played, or things along those lines.

Comment: Any new developments? I am currently struggling to add this feature to my app too.